# Manage thousands of columns in single table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

In SQL, we can manage thousands of columns in a single table.
Is it better to divide the table into one-to-one relationships or keep columns in one table, or is there another way to manage it?

In addition, we need to know the best approach and how to manage the column when performing CRUD operations.

Comment: This certainly sounds like you have a denormalisation issue. This often is the case at 100's of columns rather than 1,000's,

Comment: To see if you're doing something wrong, check if your column names have numbers in them

Comment: I agree with @ThomA. Thousands of columns in a single table most probably means you have a problem in your database design.

Comment: Unless you are using sparse columns SQL Server won't allow "thousands of columns in a single table" anyway. The max it will allow is 1024 but in practice you can end up hitting the row size limit first before getting to that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.